# Date in sql -->SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am getting "SQL command not properly ended" error while executing this query. How to check the date here

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850'
    ,TA_FROM_DATE = '02/21/2018';
```

Comment: try:
select * from table_name where EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850' **AND** TA_FROM_DATE ='02/21/2018'

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine the conditions in your `WHERE` clause using an `AND` or an `OR`, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850' AND
    TA_FROM_DATE ='02/21/2018';
```

Also note that there may be an issue with the date literal `02/21/2018` which you used.  I would write this in an ISO format, e.g. `'2018-02-21'`.  The exact format you would want to use would depend on the particular database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing Oracle error [ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/ORA-00910.html#GUID-D9EBDFFA-88C6-4185-BD2C-E1B959A97274)

You are missing the `AND` / `OR` logical operators.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850'
    AND TA_FROM_DATE = '02/21/2018';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not SQL expert, but perhaps:

```
select * from table_name where (EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850') AND (TA_FROM_DATE ='2018-02-18');
```

Answer (score 0):

To properly code it against a string variable treated as date

```
select * 
 from table_name 
where EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850'
and TA_FROM_DATE = cast('02/21/2018' as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**  The SQL statement ends with an inappropriate clause.

Use `AND` to separate your conditions

```
select * 
FROM table_name 
    WHERE 
    EMPLOYEE_ID = 'C000850' 
    AND 
    TA_FROM_DATE = cast('02/21/2018' as date);
```